# Posting the Entire List to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have got an requirement to show the textboxes in front of Every element of List item. It was easy and I did it. but now I want to post the values enetered in textboxes to controller. I am using Ajax.Begin form.Can you pl help.  A bit of Code or fiddler can be really helpful.

With the Below Code in view I have a textbox with each Code Like

testbox    Code1
textbox    Code2

User can enter values in  those textboxes and can PRess save button. And for code1, the price given in textbox should be updated in the table and so on for full list...

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SavePriceList", "Billing", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "MessageConfirmation" }))
    {

        <div id="DivFeeContent" style="float: left; width: 100%;">
            @{
        foreach (var obj in Model.objProcedureModel)
        {
                <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
                    <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
                        <input type="text" style="width: 95px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; width: 60%;">
                        @obj.ProcedureCode
                    </div>

                </div>
        }
            }
        </div>
    } 


Model::

     public class ScheduleFeeModel
        {
            public ScheduleFeeModel()
            {
                objProcedureModel = new List<tblProcedureCode>();
            }
            public List<tblProcedureCode> objProcedureModel { get; set; }
        }

Page Load::
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
 Objmodel.objProcedureModel = ObjService.GetProcedureCode();
 return View(Objmodel);
        }
```

Comment: post tblProcedure Clas

Comment: procedurecode is of what datatype?

Comment: Varchar. but we do not have to do anything to procedure code. We have to insert a price for that code like:  Textbox[450]  -- Code1........
Code will not change . only price will be changed for that code.

Comment: procdeureCode is class, can you post that class?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<Model.objProcedureModel.Count; i++)
{
 <div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 20%;">
 <input type="text" style="width: 95px;" name="Price@(Model.objProcedureModel[i].ProcedureCode)" value=" " />
 </div>
<div style="float: left; width: 60%;">
<input type="text" name="Code@(Model.objProcedureModel[i].ProcedureCode)" value="@Model.objProcedureModel[i].ProcedureCode"/>
</div>

                </div>
 }
```

and in action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ScheduleFeeModel model,FormCollection form)
{
foreach(var item in model.objProcedureModel)
{
string Price = form["Price"+item.ProcedureCode].ToString();
string Code = form["Code"+item.ProcedureCode].ToString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try list model binding. MVC has default model binding for lists
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/